# SQL select rows where col1 and col2 are same combination with different col3 values

Tags: sql

I am kind of not an expert in SQL.
I have a table :

`C1   || C2  || C3

    --------------------------
    abc   || 123   || ADD

    abc   || 123   || MERGE

    xyz   || 456   || ADD

    xyz   || 456   || UPDATE`

I need to get the rows which have same C1 and C2  and C3 as ADD and MERGE 
What is the SQL for that?

Comment: What should happen when `C1` and `C2` has `ADD`, `UPDATE` and `MERGE`

Comment: my table will only have this kind of set hence C1 ,C2 will never have all 3 for same C1,C2 combo

Comment: I have already answered for both the scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find `C1` and `C2` which has only `ADD` and `UPDATE` in `C3` then use this

```
select C1, C2 
from yourtable 
Group by C1, C2
Having count(case when C3 in ('ADD','MERGE') then 1 end) = count(*)
```

If you want to find `C1` and `C2` has both `ADD` and `UPDATE` in `C3` then use this

```
select C1, C2 
from yourtable 
Group by C1, C2
Having count(case when C3 = 'ADD' then 1 end) > 0
   AND count(case when C3 = 'UPDATE' then 1 end) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

To find C1,C2 where C3 ADD and MERGE without grouping

```
SELECT C1,C2
FROM
table1 t1
join table1 t2 on t1.C1= t2.C1 and t1.C2=t2.C2 and t2.C3='MERGE'
WHERE
t1.C3='ADD'
```

Comment: Getting ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: @Bidisha `SELECT t1.C1,t1.C2
FROM
table1 t1
join table1 t2 on t1.C1= t2.C1 and t1.C2=t2.C2 and t2.C3='MERGE'
WHERE
t1.C3='ADD'`